# HTML onclick javascript string is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a normal button that triggers a javascript method:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" onclick="sendSms()">Skicka!</a>

function sendSms() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: sendSms + '?message=' + encodeURIComponent($("#textArea").val()),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: 'true',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#loading").show();
            $("loadingSmsText").show();
            $("#smsSenderRow").hide();
        },
        success: function (smsSendResponse) {
            $("#smsSenderRow").append(smsSendResponse);
            $("#loading").hide();
            $("loadingSmsText").hide();
            $("#smsSenderRow").show();
        }
    });
}
```

When I click the button I get: `uncaught type error: string is not a function`, at this row, which is not even in my code:

```
<script>(function() {with (this[2]) {with (this[1]) {with (this[0]) {return function(event) {sendSms()
};}}}})</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the stack trace to trace it back to your code.

Comment: what are you getting from `smsSendResponse`?

Comment: `sendSms` seems to be a function, but you use it like a string in `url` definition. Is there something you don't show us?

Comment: I added a console.log in the first row in sendSms method, but it doesn't get triggered.

Comment: you need to either rename your sendSms function or rename the string variable for the url

Comment: @Teemu that solved my issue, there's over 2k more rows of javascript, and i had a variable declaration with same name.

Comment: global functions/variables are fun.